# Java - check if another Java application is running

Tags: java, monitoring, restart

I have few java application running 24/7. I'd like to write another java application, which checks if any of this applications crashes or not. If some application has crashed i'd like to restart it. Is there any solutions for this?

Comment: This sounds like a OS task to me. Which system(-s) are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I see some ways but there should be better ways to do it :

1. If you have control over your running applications you can make each of them listen to a given port on the machine and reply to any request on it. Then you can simply ping that port to see if the app is running.
2. If you launch the apps by yourself you can store their pid and then check if the process with that pid is still alive.
3. Each app can create a file and update it regularly. Then your monitoring app can check if the file has been updated. if not, then the app is dead.

Comment: "Pinging a port" works if the crash also takes down the part listening to the port. You might have a situation where everything else has crashed (e.g. hanging in a race condition) and only the port listener happily strolls along responding to pings.

Answer (score 0):

What i can think is you can define a new custom exception in those 24/7 running programs, add that exception to blocks where you think crash can occur, and then call some method of the another java application when this exception is called by the crash.

Comment: ...like in `main` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wmic utility.
Like this : `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic.exe");`

Then you may check for the different params associated with your java app (javaw.exe) application.

Comment: @Astaz3l you should ask that on superuser.com ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use the ( http://quartz-scheduler.org/ ) Quartz scheduler, or the java.util.Timer api to wake up recurrently.and check for the process. Ever time u run the process I believe u can get the PID or process ID which can be stored. 
Wake up at regular intervals and invoke a shell sript to check if the process is running. If not then spawn new Process using Runtime.getRuntime()

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a simple solution, your application must update an external resource from inside the core functionality of the application. If the external resource is not updated for a while, you know that the core of your application has stopped.

If you use a separate thread to update the resource, your core functionality will crash but the thread keeps on running and you detect nothing.

The external resource can be a file. Write the current time stamp there. If the time stamp is not updated for a while, then the app has crashed. Or write to a network socket if your monitor is on a separate machine to detect hardware crashes (a monitor is pretty useless if it crashes with your application).

Your monitor must know the process identifier of the Java process so that it can kill it and restart it when needed. you can write the process identifier into a file if you start the app from a shell script.

There exists a billion dollar industry that produces this kind of software monitors. It is not a trivial task.